# Laravel Error - Route [appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal/{id?}] not defined

Tags: laravel

In Laravel-5.8 project, From this controller:

```
public function manager_employee_goal($id)
{            
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;
    $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();
    $linemanager = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('line_manager_id')->where('id', $userEmployee)->first();
    $linemanageremployee = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('id')->where('line_manager_id', $linemanager->line_manager_id)->pluck('id');   
   $appraisedemployees = HrEmployee::select('id', 'employee_code', 'first_name', 'last_name')->where('id', $id)->get();   

    $goals = AppraisalGoal::where('employee_id', $id)->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities->id)->where('is_published', 1)->where('id', '!=', $linemanager->line_manager_id)->get();
    return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal')->with('goals', $goals)->with('appraisedemployees', $appraisedemployees);        
}
```

I navigaed to:

```
public function manager_employee_goal_list($id)
{
    $goal           =       AppraisalGoal::findOrFail($id);
    $goaldetails    = AppraisalGoalDetail::where('appraisal_goal_id', $id)->get();
    $goalcomments    = AppraisalGoalComment::where('appraisal_goal_id', $id)->get();
    return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list')
                ->with('goal', $goal)
                ->with('goaldetails', $goaldetails)
                ->with('goalcomments', $goalcomments);       
}
```

using:

```html
<a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="{{ route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list', ['id'=>$goal->id]) }}">
    {{ trans('global.view') }}
</a>
```

When I wanted to navigate back to:

> public function manager_employee_goal($id)

I used:

```html
<div class="panel-heading clearfix">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="float-right">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                <a href="{{ route("appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal/{id?}") }}" class="btn bg-navy margin" title=" Back">
                    <span> Back to List</span>
                </a>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I got this error:

> Route [appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal/{id?}] not defined

These are my route/web.php:

```
Route::get('appraisal_goals/manager_employee_goal/{id?}', 'Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsController@manager_employee_goal')->name('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal');
Route::get('appraisal_goals/manager_employee_goal_list/{id?}', 'Appraisal\AppraisalGoalsController@manager_employee_goal_list')->name('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal_list');
```

How do I resolve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just pass employee_id from goal it will fixed.

```html
<div class="panel-heading clearfix">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="float-right">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
                <a href="{{ route("appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_goal",['id'=>$goal->employee_id]) }}" class="btn bg-navy margin" title=" Back">
                    <span> Back to List</span>
                </a>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```